# Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint functionality on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp, qt4, widget

I'm currently developing a cross-plataform virtual keyboard. In linux i was able to do whatever i want, but in Windows i'm having problems to prevent the widget to obtain the keyboard focus.

In linux, using the window flag

```
Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint
```

the widget never gets the keyboard input, but of course, that flag does not work on Windows

Is there something equivalent to that flag or some method i can use instead?

any ideas would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus) on the widget that shouldn't have focus? If you want a border-less widget try setWindowFlags( Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint ) instead of Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint.

Comment: I'd tried, it doesnt work in the way i want. The Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint allows me to work with any window, not only my app's... in a x11 system.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted an answer to a similar question over in [Make a floating QDockWidget unfocusable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18577570/14312). On Win32 you don't really have the choice of bypassing the window manager completely, but you should be able to get most of the behavior you want by intercepting nativeEvent to handle WM_MOUSEACTIVATE.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to ignore the event. I believe you need to ignore `FocusIn` on the main application window - not sure about the actual event, you might need to prototype it. You can do ignore events by either installing an event filter or manually re-implementing one of the `event` methods (possibly `event` itself). I don't know which is the preferred way though but I'd attempt the event filter first for this task: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qobject.html#eventFilter

I've never tried to capture the keyboard focus event, but I have been able to successfully ignore escape keys in a `QDialog` to prevent users from accidentally closing the window. I believe it should be possible.