# Make a floating QDockWidget unfocusable

Tags: qt

I'm creating a simple virtual keyboard in a QDockWidget...
When the widget is docked into the QMainWindow, the selected widget (for example a qdoublespinbox) is highlighted and if I click on the virtual keyboard clearFocus() works...

When the QDockWidget is floating above the window and I click a button, clearFocus doesn't work and I can't see the focused widget in QMainWindow...

How can I force the QDockWidget to not have any focus at all?

Thanks :-)

This is the code:

```
// class MyVirtualKeyboard : public QDockWidget

void MyVirtualKeyboard::sendKey(Qt::Key key, Qt::KeyboardModifier mod)
{
    this->clearFocus();

    QMainWindow *w = dynamic_cast<QMainWindow *>(this->parent());
    if(w == NULL) return;

    QWidget *widget = w->focusWidget();

    QString repr = QKeySequence(key).toString();

    QKeyEvent *pressEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, key, mod, repr);
    QKeyEvent *releaseEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, key, mod, repr);

    qDebug("%s", pressEvent->text().toAscii().data());

    MyApplication *app = MyApplication::myInstance();

    app->postEvent(widget, pressEvent);
    app->postEvent(widget, releaseEvent);
}

void MyVirtualKeyboard::on_BTN_1_clicked()
{
    sendKey(Qt::Key_1);
}

...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a better way to do it!
Just use `this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_X11DoNotAcceptFocus);` and voila!

Example:

```
MyVirtualKeyboard::MyVirtualKeyboard(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyVirtualKeyboard)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_X11DoNotAcceptFocus);
}
```

Comment: This attribute however is highly platform specific (Linux, X11) and I would not use it unless being sure that the specific software always will run on that specific platform.

Answer (score 2):

The `clearFocus()` call should be unnecessary. Your dock widget and all of its widgets must have the `Qt::NoFocus` policy.

The code below shows how you might do it.

[image: screenshot]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/vkb-focus-18558664
#include <QtGui>
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
#include <QtWidgets>
#endif

class Keyboard : public QDockWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   QWidget m_widget;
   QGridLayout m_layout{&m_widget};
   QToolButton m_buttons[10];
   void sendKey(Qt::Key key, Qt::KeyboardModifier mod)
   {
      if (! parentWidget()) return;
      auto target = parentWidget()->focusWidget();
      if (! target) return;

      auto repr = QKeySequence(key).toString();
      auto pressEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, key, mod, repr);
      auto releaseEvent = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, key, mod, repr);
      qApp->postEvent(target, pressEvent);
      qApp->postEvent(target, releaseEvent);
      qDebug() << repr;
   }
   Q_SLOT void clicked() {
      auto key = sender()->property("key");
      if (key.isValid()) sendKey((Qt::Key)key.toInt(), Qt::NoModifier);
   }
public:
   explicit Keyboard(const QString & title, QWidget *parent = nullptr) : Keyboard(parent) {
      setWindowTitle(title);
   }
   explicit Keyboard(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDockWidget(parent) {
      int i{};
      for (auto & btn : m_buttons) {
         btn.setText(QString::number(i));
         btn.setProperty("key", Qt::Key_0 + i);
         m_layout.addWidget(&btn, 0, i, 1, 1);
         connect(&btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(clicked()));
         btn.setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
         ++i;
      }
      setWidget(&m_widget);
      setFeatures(QDockWidget::DockWidgetFloatable | QDockWidget::DockWidgetMovable);
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QMainWindow w;
   w.setCentralWidget(new QLineEdit);
   w.addDockWidget(Qt::TopDockWidgetArea, new Keyboard("Keyboard", &w));
   w.show();
   return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent a widget from taking focus by setting [QWidget::focusPolicy](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) = [Qt::NoFocus](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum).

However, there are two concepts here that you're mixing  - the focused control (per window), and the active window (per desktop). I think in the scenario you're describing (a torn-off popup window), the OS window manager is likely to still change the active top-level window even if Qt doesn't set a focused control. That will result in nobody having keyboard focus (which is a valid state!).

So I think a full answer to your question will involve some non-portable bits. I don't know what GUI environment you're working in, but I know some of the answer for Win32, so I'll keep going and hope that's useful:

## Win32

There's a pretty good discussion of the state tracking for Win32 on MSDN in the article [Win32 Activation and Focus](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/08/02/686141.aspx). I'm not aware that Qt does anything to wrap this level, so you'd have to use [QWidget::nativeEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) or [QCoreApplication::installNativeEventFilter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qcoreapplication.html#installNativeEventFilter) to get at the low-level event. If you can subclass the window, I'd prefer the former, since it's more self-contained.

```
bool FooWidget::nativeEvent(const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, long * result)
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    if(eventType == "windows_generic_MSG") {
        const MSG *msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG *>(message);
        if(msg->message == WM_MOUSEACTIVATE) {
            *result = MA_NOACTIVATE;
            return true;
        }
    }
#else
    #error Need platform-specific code to suppress click-activation
#endif
    return false;
}
```

This should block the click from activating the window (`MA_NOACTIVATE`), and block Qt from processing it further (`return true`), while leaving other all events (including the the click, since we *didn't* use `MA_NOACTIVATEANDEAT` to block it too) to be processed into QEvents and Qt signals normally (`return false` at the end).

If you need further low-level access (though I don't think you will), see also [QWidget::effectiveWinId()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#effectiveWinId) and [QWidget::windowHandle](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#windowHandle)

Comment: I kinda having this kind of issue: how to prevent a click on a button within a floating window (QFrame) to shift focus from the main application window? Currently I simply return back the focus to the main widow, `mainwindow.activateWindow()`. But surely it gives an unpleasant title bar flashing effect. Can it be solved?

Comment: I believe the technique of filtering WM_MOUSEACTIVATE/MA_NOACTIVATE should work for that as well.

Comment: I've been trying to intercept WM_ACTIVATE, returning False. But the effect is the buttons in that window will never get click event. Which is shouldn't be the expected result

Comment: WM_ACTIVATE is just a post-facto notification that the activation has already changed, and returning false just means you didn't process it and the event should pass to the parent window. You need to use WM_MOUSEACTIVATE and return MA_NOACTIVATE to accept the click but not become active.

Comment: Hi Puetzk, thanks for your solution. Can you please tell us which macro we have to use it for Touch screen. Your code works fine only for the mouse clicks. I tried using WM_TOUCH, but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Probably [WM_POINTERACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh454921(v=vs.85).aspx)? I've never worked with touch events, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to [Martin Gräßlin](https://plus.google.com/115606635748721265446) for the answer!

> My recommendation: check out the virtual keyboard code in KDE Plasma: http://quickgit.kde.org/?p=kdeplasma-addons.git&a=blob&h=5628d6325afe57f85917dad865a07d4116335726&hb=a658d1e257cfca2a43c12714d026ec26f1fdb755&f=applets%2Fplasmaboard%2Fwidget.cpp
>
> Looks like the key is setWindowFlags(Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint) and setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)

```
MyVirtualKeyboard::MyVirtualKeyboard(QWidget *parent) :
    QDockWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyVirtualKeyboard)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->connect(this, SIGNAL(topLevelChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(topLevelChanged()));
}

void MyVirtualKeyboard::topLevelChanged()
{
    if(this->isWindow())
    {
        this->setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);
        this->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
        this->show();
    }
}
```