# How simulate the key press event by Qt and use it in JavaScript of QML?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, keypress

I write a program for embedded and my device have physics button and clickable icons above of this buttons. 
User can press buttons or touch icons. Icons must generate keycode as buttons keycode.
So icons must simulate keypress event and translate it to focused items.
I new in Qt and QML.
The some tips [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-15496) very little help me.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to post a synthetic key event to the window that displays the QML scene. I have [an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18577450/1329652) in another answer.