# Qt5 QTreeView editable with virtual keyboard

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview, kiosk, virtual-keyboard

Working on a touch-screen kiosk system that has a virtual keyboard widget.  In all dialogs, the virtual keyboard is the only method of non-touch input.  I am now working on a QTreeView for displaying file names using QFileSystemModel, and I have added a column called New Name (all other columns other than Name are hidden).  I have overridden createEditor() and destroyEditor() for the delegate I assigned to the QTreeView, and have overridden the data() and setData() for the model.  The createEditor() override returns a pointer to a local QLineEdit object so that I can control the results of the edit (plugging them in to my model's data object for that new column).

With my physical keyboard I am able to make changes to the New Name cell for the given row, but I cannot figure out how to type on my virtual keyboard without losing focus and calling destroyEditor() on the item I'm editing.  Any ideas as to how this can be done?  I've dug into the Qt code, but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual keyboard must not have any focusable widgets. It should be focus-neutral. It won't be stealing the focus, then. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18577450/1329652) has a working example that doesn't steal focus and synthesizes keypress events that get posted to the focused widget.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input.  Got dragged in a different direction, but I just changed my code so that the constructors for the virtual keyboard widget, and for the button widgets all have the following two lines:
    setWindowFlags(Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint);
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
Works perfectly.  Thanks again.

Comment: Btw, seems that I did have to put this in both the keyboard and keybutton constructors or it didn't seem to work.  Also, both of these were necessary, where neither one worked on its own.

Comment: Btw, I do have one more issue I'm seeing now.  When I click on the item, I want to populate it with some starter text, and when I click away from the item and then click back on it, I don't want it to be blank but I want it to continue  showing the text that was in the cell before the editor was applied.  In createEditor(), I first set the QLineEdit object with the text I want it to show, and then return it.  But there is no text shown.  Seems like it's getting blanked when passed back to the Qt caller.

Comment: @bmahf If you have a separate question, ask it separately. Make sure to include a minimal testcase reproducing it!